# Complete a String containing comma and dot separated integers

Tags: java, string, algorithm

**Question:**

Given an input String like "1,2,3..6..8,9..11", we have to convert it into "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11". So basically we have to populate the ranges mentioned by dots. Below is my solution. Is there any better way to solve this ? Can we optimize this further ?

```
    public class FlattenAString {

    public static String flattenAString(String input) {
        StringBuilder sbr = new StringBuilder("");
        StringBuilder current = new StringBuilder("");
        StringBuilder next = new StringBuilder("");
        int i = 0;
        while (i < input.length()) {
            if (input.charAt(i) == '.') {
                i = i + 2;
                while (i != input.length() && input.charAt(i) != '.' && input.charAt(i) != ',') {
                    next.append(input.charAt(i));
                    i++;
                }
                int currentInt = Integer.parseInt(current.toString());
                int nextInt = Integer.parseInt(next.toString());
                appendFromCurrentTillPrevToNextInt(currentInt, nextInt, sbr);
                current = next;
                next = new StringBuilder("");
            } else if (input.charAt(i) == ',') {
                sbr.append(current);
                sbr.append(',');
                current = new StringBuilder("");
                i++;
            } else {
                current.append(input.charAt(i));
                i++;
            }
        }
        sbr.append(current);
        return sbr.toString();
    }

    private static void appendFromCurrentTillPrevToNextInt(int current, int val, StringBuilder sbr) {
        for (int i = current; i < val; i++) {
            sbr.append(i);
            sbr.append(',');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like a good question for Code Review (https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: If its given that all the numbers from `[1..n]` are present, cant we just take the first and the last number and fill all the other numbers between them?

Comment: @Oswald : That is indeed best solution in case no integer is missing. Thanks

Comment: @SahilGupta I don't think you need `StringBuilder` here, because you don't need to actually build any strings.  Instead, just consume the input string as it is.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen If you want to output a comma-separated `String` instead of a `List<String>`, `StringBuilder` seems very appropriate.

Comment: @Dukeling His code is good...I initially didn't read it closely enough before I dropped that comment.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this by splitting your input string twice.  First, split by comma to get either single numbers or ranges with ellipsis.  For single numbers, simply add them to a list.  For ranges, do a second split on `..` to obtain another list of numbers.  Then iterate over the range of each of these pairs to fill in the missing values.

Note one tricky point here is that we need to avoid double counting a number position in a range.  This is best explained by example:

```
3..6..8
```

For this range, we first add `3, 4, 5, 6`.  But for the second ellipsis, we begin at *7*, and then continue until hitting `8`.

```
String input = "1,2,3..6..8,9..11";
String[] parts = input.split(",");
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

for (String part : parts) {
    if (!part.contains("..")) {
        list.add(Integer.parseInt(part));
    }
    else {
        String[] ranges = part.split("\\.\\.");
        for (int i=0; i < ranges.length-1; ++i) {
            int start = Integer.parseInt(ranges[i]) + (i == 0 ? 0 : 1);
            int end = Integer.parseInt(ranges[i+1]);
            for (int j=start; j <= end; ++j) list.add(j);
        }
    }
}

// print list of numbers
for (int i=0; i < list.size(); ++i) {
    System.out.print((i > 0 ? ", " : "") + list.get(i));
}
```

**Output:**

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: Don't you think your solution adds on to space complexity. Since you are taking an array(parts) to hold the tokens.

Comment: Yes, the arrays take up space, but your approach also appears to do this.  The space my approach uses is proportional to the size of the input string/the quantity of numbers in the final range.  In any case, leveraging `String#split()` massively reduces the complexity of the overall problem, and I have no issues using a little space.

Comment: What if the size of string is very large ? Would you still be holding n objects at a time into memory ? My solution doesn't hold n extra space into the memory at a time, it is acting like a buffer, which is flushing data to output StringBuilder.

Comment: The amount of space my solution uses is proportional to the size of the input string.  You also need to examine running time complexity.  Your solution may be space efficient, but what about its performance?  Also, code needs to maintained by human beings, I would rather maintain my answer than yours.

Comment: Why do you think my code will add on to time complexity ?

Comment: @SahilGupta I read through your solution, and it looks good.  The only issue is that it would be harder to understand and maintain than what I have given (IMHO).  Are you working under very tight memory constraints, e.g. developing an Android app?

Comment: @TimeBiegelsien : There is no such requirement, but anyways the code must be optimized in terms of both space and time. Yes i do agree the code should be made more readable and maintainable and my point of concern here was not that :)

Comment: I will leave up my answer if you don't mind, since it is a viable alternative to what you gave.  And IMHO it is preferable from the point of view of ease of understanding and maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
static final Pattern RANGE = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)(\\.\\.(\\d+))+");

static String flattenString(String input) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();
    Matcher m = RANGE.matcher(input);
    while (m.find()) {
        int begin = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
        int end = Integer.parseInt(m.group(3));
        temp.setLength(0);
        for (int i = begin; i <= end; ++i)
            temp.append(",").append(i);
        m.appendReplacement(sb, temp.substring(1));
    }
    m.appendTail(sb);
    return sb.toString();
}
```